# Updating information in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

i want to update the user information on database im using c#.
here is my code, it doesnt work and it doesn't give me any errors.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbldisplay.Text = "<b><font color=BLUE>" + "WELLCOME:: " + "</font>" + "<b><font color=white>" + Session["Name"] + "</font>";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STUDENT-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_BuyBid;Integrated Security=True");
}
protected void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this will redirect the page to the home.aspx page.
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //creating a new connection to the database
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STUDENT-PC;Initial Catalog=BuyBid;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True;");
    con.Open();
    //creates a new sqlcommand to update the buyer's information to the Database.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BUYER SET Name = @Name,Surname = @Surname,Email =@Email,CellNumber =@CellNumber", con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtNameUpdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurnameUpdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemailUpdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellNumber", txtCellUpdate.Text);

   int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd recommend EntityFramework instead of using the SQL API with your own queries.

Comment: Have you traced your query with SQL Server Profiler? Does some command actually being sent to server? Side note: you are using `update` without `where` condition - so you will update **all** rows in your table to the same values.

Comment: i think op should first elaborate on the "it doesnt work" part. how exactly it "doesnt work" ? @op if you dont get any error, then maybe the code **does** work, just not the way you want it to.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: `int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` did you get any affected rows count in `rows` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are opening a connection (which is correct) but then you are opening it again.

That is why the update is not occurring. Also you need not close your connection in a finally statement. For the purpose of this, it is not required.

Also you are executing an Update Statement, so please ensure that you give it a condition to update the specific record.

I have edited your code appropriately, this should solve your problem:
(Tried and Tested)

---

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //creating a new connection to the database
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STUDENT-  PC;Initial Catalog=BuyBid;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous  Processing=True;");
            con.Open();
            //creates a new sqlcommand to update the buyers information to the   Database.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BUYER SET Name = @Name,Surname  = @Surname,Email =@Email,CellNumber =@CellNumber WHERE Email =@Email", con);
        //con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtNameUpdate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurnameUpdate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemailUpdate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellNumber", txtCellUpdate.Text);
            cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
   finally
   {
       // close connection if it is still open

       // editing from phone so just writting the comments here
    }
}
```

---

Let me know of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this with Asynchronous processing set to false. NB all rows in the table will be updated as you have no restriction in place in your query ie no Where clause.

```
 try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STUDENT-PC;Initial Catalog=BuyBid;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=False;");
    //creates a new sqlcommand to update the buyer's information to the Database.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BUYER SET Name = '" + txtNameUpdate.Text + "' ,Surname = '" + txtSurnameUpdate.Text + "', Email = '" + txtemailUpdate.Text + "', CellNumber = '" + txtCellUpdate.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();

    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Ex.TargetSite, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
 }
```

Comment: why no SQL parameters?

Comment: Because you don't actually need them. For example update Buyer set Name = 'Fred' where Name = 'Freddy'

Comment: so because you're not forced to use them u don't use them? I think it's better pratice to use them.

Comment: I suppose it depends on where you have come from. I have come from an sql development background into using c#. An SQL query is essentially a string that gets executed on the SQL server, so it is just about building the correct string.

Comment: I only use parameters when calling SQL stored procedures

Comment: @Ewan By not using parameters you are opening a door for sql injection to happen so you should use them.

Comment: @Ewan if you don't give about SQL injections dont use SQL parameters

Comment: In practice I always use stored procedures to update SQL databases so that I can create audit logs etc. So in effect I always use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have used try catch or your code:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //creating a new connection to the database
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STUDENT-PC;Initial Catalog=BuyBid;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True;");
        con.Open();
        //creates a new sqlcommand to update the buyer's information to the Database.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BUYER SET Name = @Name,Surname = @Surname,Email =@Email,CellNumber =@CellNumber", con);
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtNameUpdate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurnameUpdate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemailUpdate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellNumber", txtCellUpdate.Text);
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

use it an trace, check if con.open(); is true, and if any catch happen.